# Linux: how to set up a timezone of a process?

Tags: linux, command-line, timezone

I'd need to set timezones of individual processes started on a linux box. I tried setting **TZ** variable (in the local context), but it didn't work.
Is there a way of running an app from a command line with a different system date to the system one? It might sound stupid, but I need a kind of a *sandbox* where the system date would be changed.
Starting a virtual box is not an option ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try something similar to [dateshift](https://www.hornby.org.uk/dateshift) or [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime), both of which let you run a program with offset time.

Answer (score 4):

Which program do you use?
Setting TZ works here:

```
turboj@linux:~> date
Do 2. Sep 11:59:26 CEST 2010
turboj@linux:~> export TZ=UTC
turboj@linux:~> date
Do 2. Sep 09:59:34 UTC 2010
```

Maybe you forgot to "export"?

Comment: Nah mate, that won't do :( I'm starting a python script like that:

    TZ=GMT15 python a.py

The problem is, I have to use a dodgy C library which connects to a DB and calculates some data based on a client's timezone. Whatever happens in the library, I've got no control over it. What I know for sure: if I set the client's os to GMT15 it works fine. Unfortunately in prod environment I'm not a root user and I have to be able to change the date in a local context of a client. Does that make any sense? ;)